# Django Files Upload from Form get CSRF Forbidden on production

Tags: django, csrf, http-status-code-403, django-csrf, django-file-upload

I have a simple Django FileForm for multiple files upload (basically txts with polygon coordinates). **I don't want to save the uploaded files anywhere but only treat them on the fly (memory?)** and return a leaflet map with the polygons and a new file of mine (which transforms and exports all the txts in a .dxf format file (CAD combatible)).

I have done all the logic and my programm seems to work fine on development but on production (Heroku) **when i hit the submit button on my form I keep getting CSRF Forbidden 403 message**. I am really frustrated. I have used csfr decorators (csrf_exempt, requires_csrf_token, ensure_csrf_cookie) on my views but none seems to work. I have included
enctype="multipart/form-data"> and {% csrf_token %} on my form template.

What's the problem? It's hard for me to test and try because on development everything is ok and I have to deploy everytime only to see if another approach works.

Is it because I am not saving the files on a model and on a disk (What's the logic here?), or is it because I'm missing something on the CSRF part on my settings?

**settings.py** (when deploying)

```
"""
Django settings for myKAEK project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
from decouple import config
from decouple import config, Csv

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'mykaek-gr.herokuapp.com', 'myKAEK.gr', 'www.myKAEK.gr']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'djgeojson',
    'storages',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'myKAEKapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    "127.0.0.1",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myKAEK.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myKAEK.wsgi.application'

GOOGLE_MAPS_API = config('GOOGLE_MAPS_API')

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
#        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
#        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
#        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
#        'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
#        'PORT': config('DB_PORT'),
#    }
#}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

# STATIC_URL = 'static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR)
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
# MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
# MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

USE_S3 = config('USE_S3') == 'TRUE'

if USE_S3:
    # aws settings
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    # s3 static settings
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
    # s3 public media settings
    PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
    MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
    # 'myKAEKapp.storage_backends.PublicMediaStorage'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
    
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

# MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
# MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Heroku: Update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=120)
DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config() }
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://mykaek-gr.herokuapp.com/", "https://mykaek.gr/"]
```

**forms.py**

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    files = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

**html**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center text-center" style="padding-top: 30px; width: 500px; margin: auto;">
    <fieldset name="Multiple Files Upload">
        
    <form method="post" action="/draw-polygons/" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

      <dl><input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFileMultiple" name="files" required multiple></dl>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" style="margin-top: 10px;">Φόρτωση</button>

    </form>
    
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**view.py**

```
def upload_multiple_files(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files_list = request.FILES.getlist('files')
        
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files_list:
                try:
                    '''my code here'''
                except:
                    '''my code here'''

            '''my code here'''

            return render(request, "multiple/success.html", context)
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'multiple/multiple.html', {'title': 'myKAEK.gr | Draw Polygons', 'form': form})

def txt_dxf(request):
    topos = cache.get('topos')
    doc = ezdxf.new("R2000")
    msp = doc.modelspace()
    doc.layers.add('POLYS_FROM_TXTS')
    
    for i in topos:
        msp.add_lwpolyline(i, dxfattribs={"layer": "POLYS_FROM_TXTS"})

    out = io.BytesIO()
    doc.write(out, fmt='bin')
    out.seek(0)

    return FileResponse(out, as_attachment=True, filename='polygons_from_txt.dxf')
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('draw-polygons/', views.upload_multiple_files, name='upload_multiple_files'),
    path('draw-polygons/export_dxf/', views.txt_dxf, name='txt_dxf'),
]
```

**If I may add something I saw after my original question was posted:**

While my custom domain served through cloudflare returns
**CSRF Forbidden 403**, my herokuapp server returns for the same page
**Bad request 400**
I don't know if it's relevant but I thought I should add.

Also when I use @csrf_exempt on my view and delete {% csrf_token %} from template I get 400 Bad Request on my custom domain too.

Is it beacouse I use Cloudflare (with cache disabled) between my custom domain and herokuapp?

Please help I really need to get this function work.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this using Django Forms, it will save you from writing extra code and will handle such edge cases.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files

Comment: Are you suggesting using class based views over function based? My whole app is written with function based views. I intend to dig into class based views on my future projects. Do you think this could be the answer to my problem though? Cause I don't see any relevance.

Comment: Though class-based views give better abstraction, it is not what I am suggesting. You can use function base view as you are doing right now just use the Django Forms module to create, render and parse the form data. That way all such things related to form and its submission is handled by Django.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. Why are you saying I'm not using the Django Forms module at all? Did you see my forms.py? It's exactly the same with the example the link shows. The difference I see is that I don't use the generic class based view (FormView) for getting and handling the files which I intend to try. Did you notice anything else?